# Gsutil copy to local is failing due to composite object requires integrity checking with CRC32c,

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am facing a problem while copying the file from google cloud to local directory. File size is of 200MB.

I was able to copy the file without any issues till few weeks earlier but suddenly seeing below error.

````
copying gs://homedepot-dev/abc.fil /temp/```

==> NOTE: You are downloading one or more large file(s), which would
run significantly faster if you enabled sliced object downloads. This
feature is enabled by default but requires that compiled crcmod be
installed (see "gsutil help crcmod").

CommandException:
Downloading this composite object requires integrity checking with CRC32c,
but your crcmod installation isn't using the module's C extension, so the
hash computation will likely throttle download performance. For help
installing the extension, please see "gsutil help crcmod".


Can someone help me how can we solve this issue without importing any new packages
````

Comment: I think you can find the solution in this other Stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368191/compute-engine-use-gsutil-to-download-tgz-file-has-crcmod-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to the link iker offered. But I notice you say you can't install any new packages. If that's the case you don't have many good options. You could either switch to a different tool that doesn't depend on Python, or disable checksumming (which I strongly recommend against doing). You could also try running from a different system that has Python 3 installed - I *think* Python 3 comes with a compiled crcmod.